# Main page button is hovering when in wrong color

Tags: html, css

```css
.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  border-bottom: 7px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #ff3300;
  width: 80%;
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
}
.nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
.onpage {
  background-color: #ff3300;
}
.onpage:hover {
  background-color: #ff3300;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="onpage"><a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/register.php">Register</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So how do i remove the hover or make it hover to the same color as the bottom on the main page button border?

Comment: Couldn't you just give us the button?

Comment: Please edit your original question with the relevant code. Make it readable, see how other questions here look like. You can even make a code snippet.

Comment: Much better, the last step is to tell us what is the problem, and how would you like it to be.

Comment: Please stop adding  thank you line at the end of your question. It's irrelevant to the question itself. Instead you should tell us what's not working and what your issue is. You haven't explained the problem sufficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have some conflicting CSS rules.

In your example, the following rule:

```
.nav li a:hover {background-color: #111;}
```

has a higher specificity than

```
.onpage {background-color: #ff3300;}
```

so the dark gray background overrides the orange/red background.

You can work around it by overriding the dark gray color as follows:

```
.nav li.onpage a {background-color: transparent;}
```

There are other ways of achieving the same thing.

There is no need to use the `!important` rule in this case.

```css
.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  border-bottom: 7px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #ff3300;
  width: 80%;
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
}
.nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
.onpage {
  background-color: #ff3300;
}
.nav li.onpage a {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="onpage"><a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/register.php">Register</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this rule to the bottom of your css

```
.onpage,
.onpage a:hover {
   background-color: #ff3300 !important;
}
```

Comment: @RichardOlsenSandberg Try that.

Comment: But I would suggest not adding `!important`. Just increase the specificity.

Comment: @ManojKumar this works like it should work for my use, as i use JS Attributes too, just for changing between classes...